# Path of parent directory is different in pycharm then on terminal Python

Tags: python-3.x, path, ubuntu-18.04

I have a small piece of python code :

```
import os

curr_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
print("Path {}".format(curr_path))
```

I have written this in `pycharm` ide. When running this, it gives me below output:

```
Path /home/andrew/Documents/PythonProject
```

which is correct. But when I run this using terminal `python3 test.py`, it gives no output:

```
Path
```

I have double checked everything and all looks good. What could be the reason for this behavior. Thanks

Comment: How are you executing the file? What is the output of ``print("Path {!r}".format(curr_path))``

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I have mentioned the command `python3 test.py`. Let me check the output what you mentioned in comment

Comment: @MisterMiyagi When running `print("Path {!r}".format(curr_path))` in pycharm, I am getting output as `Path '/home/andrew/Documents/PythonProject'` but when running on terminal using `python3 test.py`, I am getting `Path ''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guarantee that `__file__` is an absolute path. Executing `python3 test.py` means the path is just the relative path `test.py` *with no parent directory*.

Enforce an absolute path before looking up the parent directory.

```py
# via os.path
curr_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
# via pathlib
curr_path = pathlib.Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
```